# Sigma additivity on semi-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose we have a semi algebra $\mathcal{A}=\{(a,b]: -\infty<a \le b < \infty \}$.
How to show that measure defined on this semi-algebra as
\begin{align}
\mu((a,b])=F(b)-F(a)
\end{align}
is sigma additive where $F(x)$ is a distribution function. 
Please treat me as beginner. Thank you very much for any help in advance.

I can show that for $(a,b]=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty(a_i,b_i]$ then
\begin{align}
\mu((a,b]) \ge \sum_{i=1}^\infty (F(b_i)-F(a_i))
\end{align}

But how to show reverse inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reverse inequality is really tricky you need to use that $F$ is right continuous. Using the same notation.

Since $F$ is right continuous, for all $j$, there is $d_j>0$ s.t. $F(b_j+\delta_i)\le F(b_j)+\varepsilon 2^{-j}$ and also $\delta>0$ s.t. $F(a+\delta)\le F(a)+\varepsilon$, where $a+\delta<b$. Thus $$F(b)-F(a)-\varepsilon\le F(b)-F(a+\delta)$$

Notice that $[a+\delta,b]$ is compact and $\bigcup_{j\ge1}(a_j,b_j+\delta_j)$ is an open cover, so there is a finite subcover. Then using finite subadditivity we have:

\begin{align}\,F(b)-F(a)-\varepsilon\le F(b)-F(a+\delta)\le \sum_nF(b_n+\delta_n)-F(a_n)\\
\le\sum_nF(b_n)-F(a_n)+\varepsilon/2^n\\
\le\sum_nF(b_n)-F(a_n)+\varepsilon \end{align}

Thus $\mu((a,b])\le\sum_nF(b_n)-F(a_n)+2\varepsilon $. Letting $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$ completes the proof.